# Incorrect values when using the color picker?

Tags: texture-painting, color, color-management

While painting, I use the *color picker* to pick one of the color on my object. However, the color picker does not pick the exact color that I have selected.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/NphuXHr]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viewport colors are affected by lighting and color profile.
To display unchanged colors in the viewport, you need to do two things:

- use the *Emission* shader (it's not affected by lights)
- change View Transform to *Standard*

(Or just open your image texture in *Image Viewer* and pick color from there.)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping :D Choosing the color from image texture is easier and solve the problem. Would you mind to answer my another question?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/175097/blender-texture-painting/

Comment: Happy to help :). I commented on your other question about sharing files and adding images :).

Comment: What to do when picking from the image editor yields the expected color, however painting the picked color does not match the picked color?

Comment: Hello @ThomasHarris :). Could you please post this as a new question? You can link this one to provide context. Thanks.